# ng-repeat refreshed while modal dialog open- modal disappears

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I have a modal dialog open and the ng-repeat underneath is refreshed via a websocket, the modal disappears. The websocket call back refreshes the underlying ng-repeat. This causes the modal dialog to disappear and I have to refresh the browser, which goes back to the ng-repeat data.  Basically, how can I prevent this modal from disappearing when the underlying ng-repeat is refreshed? Code Snippets:

In Controller:

```js
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, adminService) {

      // Setup
      $scope.viewData = [];
      // Get Events & Alarms
      function getClientDetails() {

        adminService.getView()
          .success(function(newViewData) {
            $scope.viewData = newViewData;

          })
          .error(function() {
            console.log('Client retrieval failed.');
          });
      };
```

In Service:

```js
app.service('adminService', function ($http, $q, $rootScope) {

// interface
var service = {
    events: [],
    getView: getView

};
  function getView() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'app/services/data.php',
      params: {
        'act': 'getAFView'
      },
    }).

    success(function(data) {
      service.events = data.data;
      return (data.data);
    }).

    error(function(data) {
      console.log('error getting client data');
    });


  };
```

Some of the Markup:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in viewData | orderBy:'-EventId'| offset : currentPage*itemsPerPage |
                                        limitTo: itemsPerPage | filter:search">
                                        <td ng-class="{'danger': data.AckState === 'Unacknowledged',
                                            'active': data.AckState === 'Acknowledged',
                                            'info': data.AckState === 'Closed'}">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEventWindow{{$index}}" ng-click="Clear(data)">
                                                View
                                            </button>
                                            <div class="modal fade" id="editEventWindow{{$index}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                           <div class="modal-header">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="addContactLabel">Details</h4>
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Martin LOL...that really cracked me up.